# authentication and RouteConfig

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, security, account

in the first load my application should show me "localhost/home/index", but always redirect me to "localhost/Account/login?ReturnUrl=%2f"

this is the configuration that I have

RouteConfig

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

WebConfig

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms defaultUrl="~/Home/index" loginUrl="~/Account/login" timeout="60" />
 </authentication>
```

Controllers

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
 public class HomeController : BaseController
```

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
  public class AccountController : BaseController
```

I would like to not redirect to "localhost/account/login"

**Update**

the first load always enters the condition and the `RedirectToLoginPage` method is executed

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
  protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var load = (HomeModel)Session["SessionLayout"] == null;

...
            if (load)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                //FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();

                PageLoad();
            }

           ...
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, how i use the actionfilterattribute, i hope it helps.

Code for the actionfilterattribute;

```
namespace  CP.Controladores
{
public class ValidateCaptchaAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext 
    filterContext)
    {
         filterContext.ActionParameters["CaptchaIsValid"] = recaptchaResponse.IsValid;
         base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

code for the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[CP.Controladores.ValidateCaptcha()]
public ActionResult MailDeContacto(FormCollection values, bool 
CaptchaIsValid)
{
    // Do something
}
```

tagging the method, this filter has relevance only for the Action "MailDeContacto", otherwise you can setting in globalfilters, and the filter will have impact in all app.

Comment: Yes, it has the tag `[AllowAnonymous]
    public class BaseController : Controller`

Comment: in my web.config i use <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication> plase remove  defaultUrl="~/Home/index" and let me know, please.

Comment: the result is still the same

Comment: is rare. Try removing the basecontroller, and let the homecontroller simply inherit the controller class. I have it equal to you and it works perfectly (without the basecontroller) Maybe the error is there!

Comment: I was right, remove the BaseController from the HomeController and it works fine.
[AllowAnonymous] public class HomeController : Controller.

Comment: I use my BaseController to load information with the OnActionExecuting method, where I can load information before any controller is executed? on RegisterGlobalFilters?

  `public class BaseController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)`

Comment: Sebas  hablas español? gracias por tu ayuda, ahora mismo lo pruebo!

Comment: Excelente, amigo Manuel ;)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda sebas, con la ayuda de tu solcuion pude depurar y encontrar el error.
`FormsAuthentication.SignOut();//FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();`

Comment: Excelente, amigo Manuel, estoy iniciando en esto de las redes sociales para programadores! Me alegra haberte ayudado! Hoy por ti, mañana por mi! Quedamos en contacto. un abrazo!